# CustomEvents and React.js Components

Tags: reactjs, custom-events

In a nested component tree in React, if you want a child component to affect state in a parent component, you pass a bound callback.

Does React have a support for listening to events from deeply nested components? Right now if I have a component tree that's 5 components deeps, I need to pass the `prop` callback through every component, which is explicit and good but somewhat inflexible.

Comment: Pardon , Are you using/familiar-with redux?

Comment: I am familiar, but I was wondering if there was a Redux-less way.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out React Context. To put it simply it is a State or a Reducer (if you use it with useReducer hook), which you can share with deeply nested children without passing it as a prop.

```
const SomeContext = createContext();

<SomeContext.Provider value={useReduce(reducerFunction, initialState)}>
// children
</SomeContext.Provider>
```

And then somewhere down the chain you can use this like the following

```
<SomeContext.Consumer>
{value => <ChildComponent value={value}>}
</SomeContext.Consumer>
```

So you don't need to pass this value as props, the only thing you need is to import  this SomeContext from the file where you created it.
This was partially pseudo-code, but it reflects the idea